# Finding index of duplicate values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains duplicate values at diff diff index.
for example `{"Indian","American","Chinese","Australian","Indian","Russian","Indian"}`
as u can see the value - `"Indian"` exists at index - `0`, `4` & `6`.

I need to know all these indexes where `"Indian"` exists and create an arrayList of that.
Here is my code:

```
public void filter(){


    categoryArray = Arrays.asList(category);

    for(String k : category){
        //Log.v("filter", filterTerm);
        if(k.equals(filterTerm.toLowerCase()))
        {               
            int p = categoryArray.indexOf(k);                   
            Log.v("index of categArr", ""+p);
            String id = Integer.toString(p);
            indexes.add(id);


        }// end of if
    }// end of for
```

Here I get how many times duplicate occurs by getting the size of indexes(ArrayList)
but when I check the values . Its one value at all index since in the method : `indexOf()` it always brings the index of first value that it finds in the Array.

So if duplicate exists at index - `2`,`5`,`7`
I get the array size of index as `3`.
But the values are `{2,2,2,};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know which index in the array you are currently at, not the first index where it is to be found. To keep track of that, put

```
int i = 0;
```

before the loop, and at the *very end* of the loop put

```
i++;
```

Then the variable `i` tells you where you have found the value, so you can add `i` to the indexes list.

Answer (score 3):

This is a situation where an index-based for loop is more appropriate than enhanced for loop that you're using, as what you need to grab is the index.

You can base all your work on the original array rather than converting it to a list, and I suspect you were going for case-insensitive match.

```
public void filter(){
    for(int i=0; i<category.length; i++){
        if(category[i].equalsIgnoreCase(filterTerm))
        {               
            String id = Integer.toString(i);
            indexes.add(id);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an ArrayList rather than an array, of course similar code will work, but using `list.get(i)` instead of `category[i]`.

Comment: Yes, this solution is slightly more efficient, as the iterator created implicitly by the original for loop would maintain its own separate index.

Comment: could you explain what is filterTerm in this answer ??